# how do i update the li instead of adding the li to the dom?

Tags: javascript, dom, fetch-api

so I want the li inside the ul to be updated everytime the button is clicked. but instead the li is getting added to the ul .
async function poke(link){
const response= await fetch(link);

```
  poke_data= await response.json();
  console.log(poke_data.name);
  console.log(poke_data.species.name);
  console.log(poke_data.weight);
  console.log(poke_data.abilities[0].ability.name);
  console.log(poke_data.sprites.other.dream_world.front_default);
  console.log("MOVES");
//   elem.appendChild(ability_ul);
 
  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    //   console.log(poke_data.moves[i].move.name);
    ability_li=document.createElement('li');
    ability_li.innerText=poke_data.moves[i].move.name;
    ability_ul.appendChild(ability_li); 
    
  }
```

}

button1.addEventListener("click",()=>{

```
let num = Math.floor((Math.random() * 151) );
    console.log(num);
var store = data.results[num].url;


console.log(store);
//  getApi(store);
poke(store);
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9YBb.png)

})

Answer (score 0):

Try getting the existing LIs (if any) first, like this:

```
  var items = ability_ul.querySelectorAll("li");

  for(var i=0;i<3;i++)
  {
    //   console.log(poke_data.moves[i].move.name);
    ability_li= items ? items[i] : document.createElement('li');
    ability_li.innerText=poke_data.moves[i].move.name;
    if (!ability_li.parentNode) ability_ul.appendChild(ability_li); 
    
  }
```